# What are differences between <aside> and <blockquote> tags in HTML5?

Tags: html

There are several articles about this topic but I'm not able to understand the relevant difference between  `<aside>` and `<blockquote>`.

Comment: The question seems to imply that they have something in common. What might that be? You should explain how you have understood the specifications, what you see as problemantic in them, and why would this matter. As such, the question is as vague as “what are the differences between an orange and an alligator?”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ["Aside vs. Blockquote in HTML5"](http://www.impressivewebs.com/aside-vs-blockquote-html5/):

> - If you can remove an `<aside>` from the page, and the content to which it’s tangential becomes incomplete, then you should not be using `<aside>`.
> - If you can remove a `<blockquote>` from the page, and the content around it is complete even without it, then you should not be using `<blockquote>`.
>
> So only use `<blockquote>` to quote external sources that are part of the primary content, not for ‘side’ content that’s decorative or is repeated in the primary content. The two quotes in this very article are legitimate `<blockquote>` content because without them the content would be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

`<blockquote>` tag specifies a content from other source.

`<aside>` tag specifies content to be shown aside(in side div) respective from other divs.

Answer (score 0):

The blockquote element represents a section that is quoted from another source.
— [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)

The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography. [— W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-aside-element)

Answer (score 0):

**aside**:

The `<aside>` tag defines some content aside from the content it is placed in.

The aside content should be related to the surrounding content.

**blockquote:**

The `<blockquote>` tag specifies a section that is quoted from another source.

Browsers usually indent `<blockquote>` elements.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this

http://www.impressivewebs.com/aside-vs-blockquote-html5/

the proper debate on the context can be read

Comment: Please add this as a comment, not an answer.