# Is there a usecase for <aside> vs <quote>

Tags: html, semantic-web

I'm relatively new to coding and am studying semantic HTML5.

I just came across the `<aside>` tag in which the instructive text indicated it's used for pull-quotes among other things like bibliography, footnote, etc.

I've often seen - and frankly used - `<quote>` myself, but now I wonder if it's more broadly accepted to use `<aside>`.

What's the common practice here, or are they simply interchangeable?

Comment: Since there is no such element as `<quote>`, I'm guessing `<aside>` is the preferred element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `quote` element in HTML.

From [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) for `aside`:

> Represents a section of a page consisting of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.

`blockquote` (which is what I assume you meant):

> The blockquote element represents a section that is quoted from another source.
>
> Content inside a blockquote must be quoted from another source, whose address, if it has one, may be cited in the cite attribute.

There's also `q`:

> The q element represents some phrasing content quoted from another source.

Not sure where your `aside` description is from, but generally anything you're quoting from another source, use either `blockquote` or `q`. Anything relating, but not core to another piece of content on the page, use `aside`.

Comment: My newbie roots are showing. I did indeed mean q, not quote. In any case, thanks for the clarification. I totally get the difference now.

Comment: All good amigo. I would prefer they called it `quote` myself. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533207/what-are-differences-between-aside-and-blockquote-tags-in-html5). In short, `<aside>` is for information that is related but not pivotal to the main text, while `<q>`, or the quote tag, is for information that is directly referenced in the main text and is required for the main text to make sense.

Comment: Helpful summary

Answer (score 0):

to summarize why  (and not ) should be used for pull quotes, here’s how you can determine if you’re using these elements incorrectly:

If you can remove an  from the page, and the content to which it’s tangential becomes incomplete, then you should not be using 
If you can remove a  from the page, and the content around it is complete even without it, then you should not be using 
So only use  to quote external sources that are part of the primary content, not for ‘side’ content that’s decorative or is repeated in the primary content. The two quotes in this very article are legitimate  content because without them the content would be incomplete.